# Use Fubini's Theorem to verify that $E(Y_n)=0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

Suppose $X_1,X_2$ are iid random variables with common N(0,1) distribution. Define
$$Y_n = \frac{X_1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_2|}$$.
Use Fubini's Theorem to verify that
$$E(Y_n)=0$$
Note that as as $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$Y_n \rightarrow Y:= \frac{X_1}{|X_2|}$$
and that the expectation of $Y$ does not exists.

### Proof:

$E(Y_n)= \int_{\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2} Y_n dP=\int_{\Omega_1}\big(\int_{\Omega_2} \frac{X_{1}(\omega_1)}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}(\omega_2)|} dP_{2}(\omega_2)\big)dP_1(\omega_1)=\int_{\Omega_1}X_{1}(\omega_1)\big(\int_{\Omega_2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}(\omega_2)|} dP_{2}(\omega_2)\big)dP_1(\omega_1)=\int_{\Omega_2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}(\omega_2)|}  \big(\int_{\Omega_1}X_{1}(\omega_1)\big(dP_1(\omega_1) \big)dP_{2}(\omega_2)=\int_{\Omega_2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}(\omega_2)|}  E(X_1)dP_{2}(\omega_2)=\int_{\Omega_2} 0 *\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}(\omega_2)|} dP_{2}(\omega_2)=\int_{\Omega_2} 0  dP_{2}(\omega_2)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. Try putting the integral over $\Omega_1$ on the inside:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y_n) &= \int\limits_{\Omega_1\times \Omega_2}Y_n dP = \int\limits_{\Omega_2} \int\limits_{\Omega_1} \frac{X_1(\omega_1)}{\frac{1}{n} + |X_2(\omega_2)|} dP_1(\omega_1) dP_2(\omega_2) \\
&= \int\limits_{\Omega_2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} + |X_2(\omega_2)|} \left(\int\limits_{\Omega_1} X_1(\omega_1) dP_1(\omega_1) \right)dP_2(\omega_2) \\
&=\int\limits_{\Omega_2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} + |X_2(\omega_2)|} \left(0\right)dP_2(\omega_2) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: why is $X_2(\omega)$ shouldn't it be $X_2(\omega_2)$ @MarcusM

Comment: @RobJames, Oops! You're right, it should be $X_2(\omega_2)$.

Comment: What are $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: $P=P_1 \times P_2$ They are the probabilities on $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively @JohnDawkins